# Javascript canvas animate sprite walking

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, sprite

I am trying to get a sprite to walk over a background image with canvas. Ideally, I would do this all on one canvas, but using two seems to be more efficient and easier.

What I have so far:

[Fiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/h85Gq/49/)

and

[Fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/dta790hn/39/)

Code from fiddle 1, working on the simplest form of the animation:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var spritePosition = 0;
var spriteWidth = 50;
var spriteHeight = 225;
var spriteCount = 17;
var spritePlayCount = 0;
var maxSpritePlays = 3;

var sheet = new Image();
sheet.onload = function () {
    animate();
}
sheet.src = "https://s33.postimg.cc/dapcxzmvj/sprite_walk.png";

var fps = 15;



function animate() {
    setTimeout(function () {

        if (spritePlayCount < maxSpritePlays) {
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        }

        // Drawing code goes here
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.drawImage(sheet,
        spritePosition * spriteWidth, 0, spriteWidth, spriteHeight,
        0, 0, spriteWidth, spriteHeight);

        spritePosition++;
        if (spritePosition > spriteCount - 1) {
            spritePosition = 0;
            spritePlayCount++;
        }

    }, 1000 / fps);
}
```

I want to be able to get this to walk correctly, and understand how it works. I see both use something along the lines of `sprite.width` and `sprite.height`, which I figured would be `width/columns` and `height/rows` but those dont seem to work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your coordinates are all wrong. Your spriteWidth and spriteHeight values don't match at all the ones of your [spritesheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eL5yV.png).

Also, your logic is only updating the x axis, while your sprite sheet is set up on multiple rows.
You'll need to update this logic so that you do update both the x and y source positions.

Finally, don't mix setTimeout and requestAnimationFrame like that. They never go well together.
To achieve 15FPS, you can quite easily run an requestAnimationFrame loop, which will fire at 60FPS, and simply draw only every four frames (60FPS / 4 => 15FPS).

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var xIndex = 0;
var yIndex = 0;
var cols = 5;
var rows = 4;
var spriteWidth = 265;
var spriteHeight = 200;

var sheet = new Image();
sheet.onload = function() {
  animate();
}
sheet.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/eL5yV.png";
var frame = 0;

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  // 60FPS / 4 => 15FPS
  if ((++frame) % 4 > 0) return;

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  // update the current column
  xIndex = (xIndex + 1) % cols;
  // update the current row if x is 0
  yIndex = xIndex === 0 ? (yIndex + 1) % rows : yIndex;
  // three cells are empty on the last row...
  if (yIndex === (rows - 1) && xIndex === 2)
    xIndex = yIndex = 0;
  // update both sourceX and sourceY
  ctx.drawImage(sheet,
    xIndex * spriteWidth, yIndex * spriteHeight, spriteWidth, spriteHeight,
    0, 0, spriteWidth, spriteHeight);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=350 height=350></canvas>
```

Comment: I was using a template I found, and was really unsure how to change it to work with my spritesheet. Your answer cleared a lot up, I just want to check was I correct in assuming the sprite height and width should be based directly on the number of columns and rows? Also, I upvoted but will accept when I am able to put this into my code and see!